# Organization and suborganizations share resources

Tags: jasperserver, repository-design

I'm designing a repository for multiple tenants. Each tenant (organization) has multiple sub-organizations which have another sub-sub-organizations and so on.

Some of the resources are accessed by leaf sub-organizations only but some of them are shared among whole organization sub-tree.

Good examples are company logo or datasource. A report created in any sub-organization has to be able to access it. I don't know how to design it - suborganizations can't access parent repository items. And I don't want to copy it every tree subnode. I can use public folder, but that's public for all tenants which must be isolated.

Made up example:

Logo path:
Company1\Human_resources\HR_logo.jpg

Report that should access the logo:
Company1\Human_resources\HR_subdivision1\some_report.jrxml

When i log in as HR_subdivision1 user I can't access the logo.

How can I share repository items across multiple suborganizations within one tenant?